# arm-linux-androideabi-gcc no such file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, android-ndk

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

    printf("Hello world!\n");


    return 0;

}
```

then,

```
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc test.c -o hello

test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

how to use this gcc in android project?

add systoot?

I try

```
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=bionic/libc/arch-arm test.c -o hello
```

but get the same result:

```
test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

please help !

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
 printf("Hello world!\n");
 return 0;
}

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307611/problems-compiling-object-using-arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pre-requested package using below command,

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-androideabi
```

then run the

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -o test lin.c
```

Comment: I work on putty, make whole android project is OK, in BoardConfig.mk, CROSS_COMPILE := prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-.

Comment: If  I just run gcc text.c -o hello, there is no problem

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a `gcc-arm-linux-androideabi` package any more. It seems like it was a one-off for 16.04 LTS Xenial? I need it though now.